# Is there a relation between work and energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

I am in high school, and I know that work=force*distance*cos and i also know KE=0.5mv^2 and that PE=mgh and that ME=PE+KE , but my question is if there is a relation between work and mechanical energy(ME). I also know that work can be equal the change in KE that is if the object remained same height ,but is there a formula containing work,PE,and KE?

Comment: The answer is yes. The question is did you do any prior research? If you put the question title in your favorite search engine, tons of useful results will pop up.

Comment: jasper, if i search for a relation between work and energy, I would find work=KE. I mentioned that in my question and i clearly stated that this is not the proper relation I am looking for. I want a relation between energy and work at any time and not only when the object remains at the same height

Comment: Work is change in total mechanical energy: W=dE.

Comment: work=change in KE-change in PE?

Comment: work=change in KE=change in PE

Comment: Broly, I think it is change in KE-Change in PE and not =

Comment: By mechanical energy conservation change in KE= change in PE.If we subtract we will get 0

Comment: @MichealMatar See the work-energy theorem in my answer below

Comment: @Broly What you are saying is only true when just conservative forces are involved.

Comment: @Photon That is work done by external forces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, you need to do some more research. But here are a few key points that may help.

First you need to understand the distinction between work and energy.

Even though work and energy have the same units, energy is possessed by something which makes it capable of doing work. Work is the transfer of energy from one thing to another. Heat is the other means of energy transfer.

There are two types of energy: kinetic and potential. For an isolated mechanical system the sum of the kinetic and potential energies is constant, i.e total energy is conserved, or as you have noted:

$$E_{tot}=KE+PE= constant$$

Another way of stating this is that the sum of the change in kinetic and potential energy is zero, or

$$\Delta KE+\Delta PE=0$$

The expression you gave for potential energy, i.e., $mgh$ only applies to gravitational potential energy. There are other forms as well (electrical potential energy, elastic potential energy, et.). In general, potential energy is the energy associated with position. Kinetic energy is the energy associated with motion.

The relationship between work and mechanical kinetic energy is given by the work-energy theorem, which states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy, or

$$W_{net}=\frac{mv_{f}^2}{2}-\frac{mv_{i}^2}{2}$$

Where $f$ and $i$ are the final and initial velocities of the object,  respectively.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Work transfers energy from one object to another. We can calculate the work done by using the force and distance moved parallel to the force while that force is acting. If work is done on an object, the kinetic energy of that object changes.

In systems of objects, we often have multiple objects interacting with each other with a variety of forces. If the work done by a force on object A is totally reversible between two different position of A, then we say that the force is "conservative":
$$\text{If }W_{1\to 2}=F_{\parallel D}D_{1\to 2 }=-F_{\parallel L}L_{2\to1}$$ where $D$ and $L$ can be two different paths between the points $1$ and $2$.

When objects interact via conservative forces, we usually don't look at the work done by those forces. We **replace** that work by calculating a "potential energy" associated with that interaction and determining the changes in that potential energy as the objects change positions.

Note

1. the potential energy belongs to the system of objects, not any one object.
2. The work done by the conservative forces is replaced by changes in potential energy.

In the traditional "drop a rock and let it fall problem" we can solve this using two different methods:

1. Looking at the work done on the rock by the gravitational force and using the work-energy theorem:
   $$ W=\Delta K=mg\Delta y$$
   $$ 0-(1/2)mv^2 = mg(0-H)$$
   $$v=\sqrt{2gH}$$
2. Using conservation of total mechanical energy on the system of rock and planet earth:
   $$E_{top}=E_{bottom}$$
   $$0+mg(y_0+H) = (1/2)mv^2+mgy_0$$
   $$v=\sqrt{2gH}.$$

Notice that I used *either* the work done by gravity (to change the kinetic energy of the rock), *or* the different gravitational potential energies of the system, but not both.  That's because potential energies are designed to replace the work done by the conservative forces.

Answer (score 0):

Work done means energy transferred .

If a car of mass 500kg is moving at a constant speed of 2m/s. Then you do not say the car has a work of 1000 joules. You say it has a KE of 1000 joules.

However, say this car loses KE due to friction with the ground, now you can say the car has done work/transferred energy to the ground.

Work done=energy transferred